# Javascript Can't compute the result?

Tags: javascript, performance, asymptotic-complexity

Below is my script

```
var num=1;
var validator =false;

while(!validator){
   for(var k=1;k<=N;k++)
   {
      if(num%k==0)
      {
        validator = true;
      }
      else
      {
        validator = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    num = num+1;
}
console.log("number is: "+parseInt(num-1));
```

The above code gives the result when N=10 i.e "the number is: 2520"
But when i change the value of N=20, the script stops responding.
Can anybody explain me why so & how can i determine till what level of computational complexity Javascript can compute.
Thanks.

Comment: N 20 = number is: 232792560 , doesnt stop for me. The limit might be your computer?

Comment: node script.js
number is: 232792560
elapsed time: 3569 ms

Answer (score 1):

No it executes but the performance is getting affected, because of the **`while`** looping.

```
number is: 232792560 //when N=20
```

Comment: i'm running it on console are you able to see the see the result in the console?

Comment: @subh yes I am able to see the result in console.  By the way it varies.